# select multiple elements with group by in spark.sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

is there any way to group by table in sql spark which selects multiple elements 
code i am using:

```
val df = spark.read.json("//path")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("GETBYID")
```

now doing group by like :

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql(
  "SELECT count(customerId) FROM GETBYID group by customerId");
```

but when I try:

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql(
  "SELECT count(customerId),customerId,userId FROM GETBYID group by customerId");
```

Spark gives an error :

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'getbyid.`userId`'
>   is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function.
>   Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care
>   which value you get.;

is there any possible way to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and the error message you attached describes all the possibilities. You can either add the `userId` to groupBy:

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT count(customerId),customerId,userId FROM GETBYID group by customerId, userId");
```

or use `first()`:

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT count(customerId),customerId,first(userId) FROM GETBYID group by customerId");
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to keep all the occurences of userId, you can do this :

```
spark.sql("SELECT count(customerId), customerId, collect_list(userId) FROM GETBYID group by customerId")
```

By using collect_list.