# Expression 'id' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Scala and Spark 1.6.3, my error message is:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'id' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. 
Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

Code that generates error is:

```
returnDf.withColumn("colName", max(col("otherCol"))
```

The DataFrame returnDf looks like:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|            otherCol|
+---+--------------------+
|1.0|[0.0, 0.217764172...|
|2.0|          [0.0, 0.0]|
|3.0|[0.0, 0.142646382...|
|4.0|[0.63245553203367...|
```

There is a solution to this when [using sql syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421675/select-multiple-elements-with-group-by-in-spark-sql?rq=1). What is an equivalent solution using the syntax that I am using above (i.e. the `withColumn()` function)

Comment: So you are actually looking for a maximum value in an array, aren't you? If that's the case you cannot use `max` at all (not that it could be applied to `array<>` column anyway). In 2.4 you can use higher order functions, but in 1.6 you'll have to use `udf` like `udf((xs: Seq[Double] => xs.max)`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do a groupBy before using aggregation functions:

```
returnDf.groupBy(col("id")).agg(max("otherCol"))
```

Comment: To make it easier for others to read your answer, try to use code formatting for code snippets. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code for information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `max` is an aggregate function, that returns the max of a column, not the max of the array in each row in that column.

To get the max of an array, the correct solution is to use a UDF:

```
returnDf.withColumn("colName", udf((v : Seq[Double]) => v.max).apply(col("otherCol")))
```